# Is ionic framework and Cordova support for windows xp 32 bit pc?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new in Android, and I am developing android app using ionic and cordova frameworks but my pc configuration is windows xp 32 bit, and I am not sure that
this configuration will support this two framework, and if it support on xp 32 bit then which version of  ionic and cordova need to download and how to install 
it on windows pc.

please help me on it Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install ionic and cordova.

1. Firstly, Install node js. Install it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. Open the command prompt and verify the Node.js version by using the command node -v.
3. To install Cordova and Ionic, use - npm install -g cordova ionic.
4. Make sure to install the latest version of JDK and Android Studio IDE for Android development.
5. To create a new project, use  - ionic start projectname template.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure either, but you could try. Due to Node [discontinuing XP support](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3804), you would need a Node version < 6.0 so try [5.9.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.9.1/node-v5.9.1-x86.msi). Ionic 4 uses web components, so I doubt you'd be able to install a browser in XP that would support them, in which case Ionic 3 would be your best bet -- installation instructions [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/installation/). You will need a browser with the best possible support, so try Firefox [52.3.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.3.0/releasenotes/).

The first step would be to get Ionic running in your browser. Install Node, then run `npm install -g cordova ionic`. Create a starter app `ionic start` and choose one of the more involved apps like the conference app. Then `cd your-new-app` and run `ionic serve`. It might open IE by default, so open Firefox and navigate to http://localhost:8100.

If that works so far, it's time to build for Android.

Android Studio is available [for XP](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads). You'll need [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html), too (warning: must create an Oracle account to download this). Go through the [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) to make sure you have everything in place (Android SDKs, environment variables etc). When that's done, run `ionic cordova platform add android` and `ionic cordova build android`. If that works and you get a "BUILD SUCCEEDED", it will be an achievement in itself -- let me know how it goes!